# Flexbox items won't set to row

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am building my portfolio using Flexbox. I wrote it in mobile view first and it worked well. When I resize the window to full size, I expect the items to line up horizontally (I set flex-flow:row wrap;) but they stay in a column.

I have tried resizing the images themselves and adjusting margin/padding/etc but nothing will get more than one item on each row. Ideally each row would hold 3-4 items.

```
.projects {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.item {
    border:1px solid white;
    padding:5%;
    margin:5% auto;
}

.item img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.caption {
    font-size:0.75rem;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Full code here: 
  http://codepen.io/duggalsf/pen/bwjpLo

Any advice would be helpful. (Also let me know if I just need to do media queries, I was given to understand that using a Flexbox grid would not require media queries) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.projects ul {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
```

you have to use *.projects ul* instead of *.projects*. heres the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h3ghowo/3/)

Answer (score 2):

please change this class :-

```
.item {
   border:1px solid white;
   padding:5%;
   margin:5% auto;
   display:inline-block; /* add this class */
}
```